# How do I use the retrained model of tensorflow-for-poets-2 using python script?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

In the tensorflow-for-poets codelabs after the training there are steps as follows:

```
python -m scripts.label_image
    --graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb\
    --image=tf_files/flower_photos/daisy/21652746_cc379e0eea_m.jpg
```

How to write a python script instead of passing commands in command prompt?
Is there a way to write a python code so that we can give the graph and image files of trained model?